# MariaDB check connection state in python

Tags: python, mariadb

Does the python [MariaDB connector](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy1.0/) has api to check the connection state similar to `is_connected` in [python-mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) or any other way to check the connection state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB Connector/C doesn't have is_connected() method, but you can check connection status with ping() method, e.g.

```
import mariadb

def is_connected(connection):
    try:
        connection.ping()
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: thanks, I guess currently there isn't any better solution then your answer or handling client errors.